# Remove subdocument from document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I would like to remove the **Path** object from the document.
I tried to use the **$unset** operator but it demands **value** which I don't have to give.
Is there a way to remove a whole sub document from document?

```
{
    "Address" : {
        "Country" : "temp",
        "City" : "temp",
        "Street" : "temp",
        "House" : "temp",
        "Apartment" : "temp"
    },
    "Birthday" : {
        "Date" : {
            "Day" : "temp",
            "Moth" : "temp",
            "Year" : "temp"
        }
    },
    "ConnectionStatus" : "Offline",
    "DisplayName" : "temp",
    "Email" : "temp",
    "FirstName" : "temp",
    "LastName" : "temp",
    "Password" : "temp",
    "Path" : {
        "Start" : {
            "Longtitude" : 400,
            "Latitude" : 300
        },
        "End" : {
            "Longtitude" : 500,
            "Latitude" : 400
        },
        "Milestones" : [ 
            {
                "Longtitude" : 420,
                "Latitude" : 320
            }, 
            {
                "Longtitude" : 450,
                "Latitude" : 350
            }, 
            {
                "Longtitude" : 480,
                "Latitude" : 380
            }
        ]
    },
    "ProgressStatus" : "Safe",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5201cadc5b4da1f65a000001")
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.coll.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5201cadc5b4da1f65a000001")}, {$unset: {Path :
1}})`

You have to give the **$unset** operator a value of **1**

Replace `coll` with your collection name

Comment: @ShaolinRabbi from the documentation:
"The value of the field in the $unset statement (i.e. "" above) does not impact the operation."
It's just a kind of a placeholder